# QGIS fails to generate requested number of random points

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-3

Does anyone have any ideas what might be blocking this process? The layer has thousands of polygons totalling hundreds of thousands of square metres, but when asked to locate 140 random points even with zero minimum spacing, QGIS claims "Could not generate requested number of random points. Maximum number of attempts exceeded." My last run has 83 points.

Working on land use data for British Columbia, Canada with QGIS 3.2.0-Bonn.

I do now have 2 runs with ~140 total, but I'd like to be able to create one set with a minimum spacing.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what process are you using to generate the random points?

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure that was the Random points in Layer Bounds function, since I'm looking for a certain number across the whole layer, and only in polygons. I think that one made the most sense.